# Progress indicator for amount of specific types of documents in a hierarchy

Tags: workflow, document-library

Im thinking of making a document libary with files that have a field "type_of_document" which gives the type of document e.g. "meeting notes". I wont make hem content types, just a column where multiple 'types' can be added for 1 file (in case the file contains multiple documents in one). Each of the documents is tied to a `collection´ number. The ´collection´ number is tied to multiple documents. I dont use document sets.

I now want to make a view where the content is categorized - ordered by that number.

Until so far that it is simple. But now: a certain amount of those 'type_of_document' will be required per 'collection number'. So now I want to place a percentage next to the 'collection number' based on the amount of 'type of document' entries matching the required list (this will probably be a workflow).

Would that be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DVWP, not a list view. You can edit the XSL to calculate the percentage. Here is an example from the [Technet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/ea26f0ed-37b5-49f5-a000-ac5a9941ea23)

> First, we should calculate the sum of the “count” column in the list. the formula is “ sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Count) ”;
>   Second, we should calculate the sum of the “count” column in every group. The formula is “ sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Category=$thisNode/@Category]/@Count) ”
>   Now, we can get the Percent of every group using “ format-number(sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Category=$thisNode/@Category]/@Count) div sum( /dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Count),'##.#% ')”

Replace @Category with @Type_of_document (i.e. the name of your column.